# Mathematical analysis about prime number

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $P$ be the set of all prime numbers and let $f$ be a function from $[0,1]$ to $P$. Prove that there exist $x,y \in [0,1]$ that $x \neq y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof by contradiction. If not, then $f$ is an one-to-one function. Hence $[0, 1]\subseteq P$. So $P$ is an uncountable set, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You are confusing $card([0,1])\leq card(P)$ with $[0,1]\subseteq P$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for any $x, y$ we have $f(x) \neq f(y)$. This means
$$
\mathrm{card} \, \mathbb{R} = \mathrm{card} \, [0, 1] \le \mathrm{card} \; P = \mathrm{card} \, \mathbb{N},
$$
which is definitely not true.

Here $\mathrm{card} X$ means [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of the set $X$.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of $[0,1]$ is strictly greater that that of P (can you prove this?). If the claim wasn't true, there would be an injective function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow P$, hence $|[0,1]|\leq |P|$ by the definition of cardinality. This is a contradiction.